# Passing ${} variable to awk without loosing it

Tags: bash, variables, sed, awk, echo

I have following string `This is ${name} ${surname}`.
This string is irreplaceable

Now I need to replace `${name}` and `${surname}` with my own data. I wanted to use sed/awk but when I type

```
string="This is ${name} ${surname}"
echo $string | awk '{... gsub() ...}'
```

then problem is that to `awk` I'm passing only `This is` because `echo` resolved `${}` which was empty.

I don't know if I can use something like

```
awk <<EOF
This is ${name} ${surname}
EOF
```

because I need to wrap it into variable and since bash is oneliner I can't type like that

```
VAR=$(awk <<
This is ${name} ${surname}
EOF)
```

Thanks for  your time

Comment: You may get an answer telling you how to do what you're trying to do, BUT what you're trying to do makes no sense. If you tell us more about WHAT you're actually trying to do rather than HOW you think you should do it, we can probably give you more useful help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes to define your string (to avoid shell expansion):

```
string='This is ${name} ${surname}'
```

Then use in awk:

```
echo "$string" | awk '{print $0}'
This is ${name} ${surname}
```

You can see how `awk` is getting unexpanded string.

Answer (score 2):

How about simple shell:

```
template='This is ${name} ${surname}'
name=Peter
surname=Falk
eval "echo $template"
```

Will print

```
This is Peter Falk
```

Is there any particular reason why you wanted to use `awk` for this simple task?

Comment: Thanks for that option too. Unfortunately `eval()` is evil since it changes my `'\n'` to `'n'` ]:<

Comment: You didn't have a `\n` in your question.  It can be taken care of if you tell me where it shall be.  Probably using `$'\n'` might solve your issue.  But if you tell me more I can be more specific.